# TypeError: line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'markers'

Tags: python, plotly, markers, plotly-express

I'm trying to use "markers" for the line function with plotly 5.4.0

```
import plotly.express as px

df_temp =  df_temp[df_temp.date_str.isin(selected_dates)]
        fig = px.line(df_temp, x='trialID', y='reaction_time', color='date_str', markers=True,
                         title=f'Graph2. Intervention status: {status}')
```

i get the error:

```
TypeError: line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'markers'
```

i read that it's about an update but i don't think it's that. does anyone know what it could be?

Comment: You should check documentation of the library and the methods

Answer (score 0):

- you have not provided a MWE.  Have simulated `df_temp, selected_dates, status`
- with this it runs without issue with **plotly** 5.4.0

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_temp = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date_str": np.repeat(pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=10), 10).astype(str),
        "trialID": np.tile(np.arange(10), 10),
        "reaction_time": np.random.uniform(0, 2, 100),
    }
)

selected_dates = pd.Series(df_temp["date_str"].unique()).sample(5).values
status = "my favorite status"

df_temp = df_temp[df_temp.date_str.isin(selected_dates)]
fig = px.line(
    df_temp,
    x="trialID",
    y="reaction_time",
    color="date_str",
    markers=True,
    title=f"Graph2. Intervention status: {status}",
)

fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Plotly's documentation marks this as a valid parameter:

> markers (boolean (default False)) – If True, markers are shown on lines.

taken from [plotly.express.line documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line.html)

For me upgrading the plotly version fixed it. You can check the plotly version with `import plotly` and then `plotly.__version__`. (You can do that for any library actually). I can't seem to find history on the API spec as to when they introduced, but from the answers above it works in 5.4, and for me it didn't work in 5.1.